# Run Multiple Scripts in Order

Tags: google-apps-script

I have 5 versions of the below script within my project that pull from google analytics (each pulling a group of pages). I currently have to run each manually, and would like them all to run, one after the other, in order. I have set it up this way to get around the 6 minute time limit.

Is there a way to run the first, and upon completion have a scripted trigger that points to the next script to automatically run?

```
function main3() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for (var i = 1; i < 32; i++) {      
    var istring = i.toString();
    var sheetName = istring;
    var istring1 = "a" + ((i+1).toString());
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    //sheet.clearContents();  
  }
  for (var j = 27; j < 40; j++) {
    var jstring = j.toString();
    var jstring1 = "d" + ((j+1).toString());
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("..."); 
    var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('GA ID & SS KEY');
    var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Dates');
    var allRows = sheet1.getRange(2, 1, 31).getValues();  
    var timeZone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
    var tableId = sheet2.getRange(jstring1).getValue();
    //var lastRow = 2;           
    for (var i = 1; i < 32; i++) {    
      var istring = i.toString();
      var sheetName = istring;
      var istring1 = "a" + ((i+1).toString());
      var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
      var startDate1 = Utilities.formatDate(allRows[i-1][0], timeZone, "YYYY-MM-dd");
      var endDate1 =  startDate1;
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      if (lastRow == 0) {
        lastRow = 2;
      } else {
        lastRow = lastRow + 1;
      }
      var metrics = ['ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews,ga:users,ga:newUsers,ga:entrances'];
      var options = {
        'dimensions': 'ga:hostname,ga:pagePath,ga:dimension3,ga:date',
        'filters': 'ga:dimension3==commerce',
        'sort': '-ga:pageviews',
        //'segment': '',
        'samplingLevel': 'HIGHER_PRECISION',
        'max-results': '10000'
      }      
      var report = gaGet(tableId, startDate1, endDate1, metrics, options);
      if (report.rows !== undefined) {    
        Logger.log(report.rows.length);
        var data = report.rows;
        var writeRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, data.length, data[0].length) 
        writeRange.setValues(data);
      }
    }
  }
}

function gaGet3(tableId, startDate1, endDate1, metrics, options) {
  // Apply standard options
  options = options || {};
  options['max-results'] = options['max-results'] || '10000';  
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    try {
      return Analytics.Data.Ga.get(tableId, startDate1, endDate1, metrics, options); 
    } catch (err) {      
      if (err.message.indexOf('a server error occurred') > -1) {
        Logger.log('Backend Error');        
        Utilities.sleep(2 * 60 * 1000);
      } else if (err.message.indexOf('User Rate') > -1) {
        Logger.log('Rate Limit Error');        
        Utilities.sleep(1000 * Math.pow((i + 1), 2));
      } else if (err.message.indexOf('too many concurrent connections') > -1) {
        Logger.log('Concurrent Connections Error');        
        Utilities.sleep(1000 * Math.pow((i + 1), 2));
      } else {
        Logger.log(err);
        throw err;
      }
    }
  }
  throw 'Error. Max retries reached';
}
```

Comment: Hello, did your issue get solved? Remember that if you want to mark your question as solved you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) whatever answer provided a solution to your problem. If that's not the case and your issue is not solved, please consider explaining why that's not the case so that this community can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I looked over your code and I think you could simplify it a lot.  For example, the first loop in the code does nothing so you can delete that.  Additionally, the code would benefit from a more experienced programmer. It could probably be a third of the size.

However, the real problem is that it looks like your calling a report from `Analytics.data.ga` and you probably have no control over it and based upon the look of your second function you had problems with calling it too fast.  So I'd be inclined to run it off of a five minute timer and store the index that runs from 1 to 31 in the `PropertiesService` do it late at night and have your reports waiting for you in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to get around the 6 minute time limit is creating a timed-based trigger at the end of each function that calls the following function after a specified amount of time.

The method to notice here is [after(durationMilliseconds)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder.html#afterdurationmilliseconds). Thanks to this, you can run whatever function you specify after the amount of milliseconds you indicate.

For example, if we had three functions which take more than 6 minutes to complete if you run them one after the other, you could do something on the following lines:

```
function myFunction1() {
  // Whatever myFunction1 does
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction2")
  .timeBased()
  .after(1000) // This fires the second function 1 second after the first one ends. Change this time according to your preferences
  .create();
}

function myFunction2() {
  // Whatever myFunction2 does
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction3")
  .timeBased()
  .after(1000) // This fires the third function 1 second after the second one ends. Change this time according to your preferences
  .create();
}

function myFunction3() {
  // Whatever myFunction3 does
}
```

Another way would be to use [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts#overview_of_the_api) to [run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts) the different functions remotely, but it's a harder workaround.

Using [libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries) is not an option, since the execution time corresponding to the libraries count as part of the original script from where these libraries are called.

And of course, the first thing to do, before using triggers, would be to increase the efficiency of your code so that it takes less than 6 minutes to run.